# Gradle, Spring Boot, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa upgrade

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa, build.gradle

I am using Spring Boot version 1.5.7.RELEASE and wanted to use some of the following code for some pagination stuff something like

```java
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 1, org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "seatNumber"));
```

However, my version of `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort` doesn't have the `by` method. When I update the individual JAR that has the `Sort` class (`spring-data-commons`) the compilation error goes away but I get a bunch of other errors.

So I tried doing something like this

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.3.4.RELEASE'
```

To hopefully more "holistically" upgrade all the Spring Data pieces, but that doesn't seem to do anything (still have the old version of `spring-data-commons`). https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.3.4.RELEASE

I assumed by "pointing" to it would upgrade all the dependencies too but I am still on hibernate 5.0 instead of (according to the Maven repository link hibernate 5.4). Anyways in summary I would like to upgrade just the spring data pieces if that is possible, with a simple one liner, or at least understand why doing what I mentioned doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Do Nhu Vy, you were right, for some reason I did try to upgrade to the latest version of boot instead of just going to an earlier release of 2.x.

When I upgraded to 2.0.5 from 1.5.8 the upgrade was pretty seamless! 

Also that did update the spring-data-commons so I could use the method on the Sort class I was wanting to. 

Thanks so much Do Nhu Vy!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading from Spring Boot version `1.5.7.RELEASE` to version `2.3.4.RELEASE` is to adventurous.

You should upgrade small piece gradually. The problem(s) will be easy to diagnostic.

Comment: Is there a way to just update the spring-data-JPA stuff libraries all at one time?

Comment: You increase version of Spring Boot step-by-step, then `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` will increase its version number (accordingly) automatically.